# Return index of maximum number in a list using enumerate

Tags: python

I have a list `a = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
My program should return a list of the "indexes" of the maximum value, in this case `[0, 5]` but I'm using enumerate and not the actual index.

```
a = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a2 = enumerate(a)
result = list(a2)
print(result)
```

This now gives me `[(0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]` but I'm unsure of how to return 0 and 5 from here. I can find them individually by trying

```
print(result[0][0])
print(result[5][0])
```

but having trouble iterating over the list of tuples to find the first element where the second element is the maximum value. I'm thinking I need to use the max function but again unsure of the syntax this should take.

Answer (score 1):

JUst get the max value of a list using `max` function. and then using enumerator match the max value with the value if the list . if they matched then store the index

```
max_value = max(a)
result = [index for index, value in enumerate(a) if value==max_value]
```

if dont want to use `max` function, and done the task in O(n)  then

```
a = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,1,1,1,4,999999]

save_index = {}
largest = -99999999999 

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v>largest:
        largest=v
    if v not in save_index:
        save_index[v]=[i]
    else:
        save_index[v].append(i)

result = save_index[largest]
print(result)
# output 10
```

Comment: The first code is also O(n)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, but just used `max` there, second one is without it

Comment: Still, `max` simply iterates the list which is O(n)...

Comment: yeah, both are O(n), difference is the memory usage and in first one we have to traverse through list 2 times (one while calulating max, and second to calcluate index), in second on it is just 1 time traversal with more memory usage

Comment: By the way you can use a `defalutdict` to simplify the second code

Comment: yes, but doesn't want to use any other function  other than `enumerator`

Comment: It's called `enumerate` and nowhere it says you're not allowed to use anything. The OP just said that they are trying to use `enumerate`...

Comment: yes, it can be solved in other ways also, just want to stick with basic code using DS and without using any library

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use `max` it's very easy:

```
a = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
results = [index for index, value in enumerate(a) if value == max(a)]
```

This is very inefficient as it runs `max(a)` on every iteration. Plus if you're unable to use `max` at all (because this sounds like an assignment) or if efficiency matters, you could do `max` first before the loop

results are `[0, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about lists is that you can use function `max()` and pass the list as a parameter to it.
You can also use **list comprehension** to build your resulting output.

```
res = [i  for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]==max(a)]
```